# Power Query/Pivot Table as reference to Data Validation

Tags: excel, vba, validation, pivot-table

## WHAT I HAVE:

I have a large dynamic table made by Power Query similar to the following format:

```
     X                     Y       
   [P27]  [M258]  [S1]  [ML06]  [RF01]
   [P27]  [M233]  [S2]  [ML08]  [RF01]
   [P27]  [M334]  [S1]  [ML10]  [RF03]
   [P32]  [M352]  [S1]  [ML01]  [RF01]
   [P32]  [M344]  [S2]  [ML01]  [RF01]
```

## WHAT I WANT:

In another sheet, I want to data validate certain cells with drop down lists (List1 & List2) based on column X and column Y, respectively.

That means, that if I first choose P27 in List1 then List2 will only show me the options related to P27 - namely ML06, ML08 & ML10.

## SOFTWARE:

I am using Excel 2016 and would gladly involve vba code.

## WHAT I TRIED

1. I tried transforming the Query into a design like the following.

```
    [P27]   [P32]
    [ML06]  [ML01]
    [ML08]  [ML01]
    [ML10]
```

but with no success.

2. I tried referencing column Y in the Query Table. This works, but it will give me a list of ALL the entries in column Y.
3. I tried making a PivotTable based on the Query Table. It can categorize my data, but I cannot manage to get it into the correct structure. On the attached picture you can see the current structure of the PivotTable and how I would like to structure it. [PivotTableStructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjVXm.png)

Is there a way to reference all the data entries inside the P27 & P32 categories of my PivotTable and use it as a Data Validation list?

Comment: Do you have the data table somewhere in the Excel Sheet or in Data Model only?

Comment: Hello Dhirendra and thanks for your reply. I have the data table inside excel in a separate sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Assume your data starts in Sheet 1 column A (you say X and Y, but those columns are next to each other and your data isn't). Also, assume your List1 data validation is in Sheet1 cell I5 (you'll have to adjust the below formula if you put it on a different sheet).

Create a named range called dvList2 with this formula

```
=OFFSET(INDEX(Sheet1!$D$1:$D$5,MATCH(Sheet1!I5,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5,FALSE)),0,0,COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5,Sheet1!I5),1)
```

Then create Data Validation of List and =dvList2.

This assumes that column X is sorted. It won't work if it's not.

The formula finds the first instance of, say, P27 and extends that list by the count of P27s in the list.